# byte[] to file in Java

Tags: java, arrays, file, io, inputstream

With Java:

I have a `byte[]` that represents a file.

How do I write this to a file (ie. `C:\myfile.pdf`)

I know it's done with InputStream, but I can't seem to work it out.

Answer (score 615, accepted):

Use [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#writeByteArrayToFile%28java.io.File,%20byte%5B%5D%29)

```
FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(new File("pathname"), myByteArray)
```

Or, if you insist on making work for yourself...

```
try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("pathname")) {
   fos.write(myByteArray);
   //fos.close(); There is no more need for this line since you had created the instance of "fos" inside the try. And this will automatically close the OutputStream
}
```

Comment: @R. Bemrose Well, it probably manages to clean up resources in the sad case.

Comment: From the doc: NOTE: As from v1.3, the parent directories of the file will be created if they do not exist.

Comment: If writing fails, you will leak the output stream.  You should always use `try {} finally {}` to ensure proper resource cleanup.

Comment: If you have to include Apache Commons IO or Guava into your project only for this reason, I suggest you to choose Commons IO over Guava, as it weighs less (204 KB versus 2.3 MB).

Comment: the fos.close() statement is redundant since you're using try-with-resources which closes the stream automatically, even if writing fails.

Comment: Why would i use apache commons IO when it is 2 lines with regular Java

Comment: @bmargulies How about charset in this case?

Answer (score 229):

Without any libraries:

```
try (FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(path)) {
    stream.write(bytes);
}
```

With [Google Guava](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/io/Files.html#write-byte:A-java.io.File-):

```
Files.write(bytes, new File(path));
```

With [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#writeByteArrayToFile%28java.io.File,%20byte%5B%5D%29):

```
FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(new File(path), bytes);
```

All of these strategies require that you catch an IOException at some point too.

Comment: How about charset in this case?

Comment: @pavan charset of `path`? FileOutputStream documentation does not mention this so this is probably platform-specific. I'd guess it is UTF-8 in the absolute most cases.
`bytes` are written as-is, no charset is involved.

Answer (score 160):

Another solution using `java.nio.file`:

```
byte[] bytes = ...;
Path path = Paths.get("C:\\myfile.pdf");
Files.write(path, bytes);
```

Comment: I don't think `C:\myfile.pdf` would work on Android anyway... ;)

Comment: @TB How about charset in this case?

Comment: charset seems irrelevant since we're writing bytes, not chars

Comment: What ever you said was true, I understood my mistake.

Answer (score 47):

Also since Java 7, one line with java.nio.file.Files:

```
Files.write(new File(filePath).toPath(), data);
```

Where data is your byte[] and filePath is a String.  You can also add multiple file open options with the StandardOpenOptions class.  Add throws or surround with try/catch.

Comment: You could use `Paths.get(filePath);` instead of `new File(filePath).toPath()`

Comment: @Halil I don't think that's right. According to the javadocs there is an optional 3rd argument for open options and "If no options are present then this method works as if the CREATE, TRUNCATE_EXISTING, and WRITE options are present. In other words, it opens the file for writing, creating the file if it doesn't exist, or initially truncating an existing regular-file to a size of 0."

Answer (score 20):

From **Java 7** onward you can use the *try-with-resources* statement to avoid leaking resources and make your code easier to read. More on that [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/trywithresources-401775.html).

To write your `byteArray` to a file you would do:

```
try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("fullPathToFile")) {
    fos.write(byteArray);
} catch (IOException ioe) {
    ioe.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I tried using this and it caused problems with bytes that weren't UTF-8 characters, so I would be careful with this one if you're trying to write individual bytes to build a file, for example.

Answer (score 4):

Try an `OutputStream` or more specifically `FileOutputStream`

Answer (score 4):

Basic example:

```
String fileName = "file.test";

BufferedOutputStream bs = null;

try {

    FileOutputStream fs = new FileOutputStream(new File(fileName));
    bs = new BufferedOutputStream(fs);
    bs.write(byte_array);
    bs.close();
    bs = null;

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace()
}

if (bs != null) try { bs.close(); } catch (Exception e) {}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
File f = new File(fileName);    
byte[] fileContent = msg.getByteSequenceContent();    

Path path = Paths.get(f.getAbsolutePath());
try {
    Files.write(path, fileContent);
} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(Agent2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

//////////////////////////  1] File to Byte [] ///////////////////

```
Path path = Paths.get(p);
                    byte[] data = null;                         
                    try {
                        data = Files.readAllBytes(path);
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(Agent1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
```

///////////////////////   2] Byte [] to File ///////////////////////////

```
 File f = new File(fileName);
 byte[] fileContent = msg.getByteSequenceContent();
Path path = Paths.get(f.getAbsolutePath());
                            try {
                                Files.write(path, fileContent);
                            } catch (IOException ex) {
                                Logger.getLogger(Agent2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                            }
```

Comment: Thanks for answer..but i have confusion regarding "fileName" i mean what is the type of file you are saving the data? can you please explain?

Comment: Hi SRam, that solely depends on your application why you are doing the conversion and in which format you want the output, I would suggest to go for a .txt format (e.g:- myconvertedfilename.txt) but again its your choice.

Answer (score 1):

> I know it's done with InputStream

Actually, you'd be [writing](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#write%28byte%5b%5d%29) to a [file output](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html)...

Answer (score 1):

This is a program where we are reading and printing array of bytes offset and length using String Builder and Writing the array of bytes offset length to the new file.

`**Enter code here**

```
import java.io.File;   
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;        

//*This is a program where we are reading and printing array of bytes offset and length using StringBuilder and Writing the array of bytes offset length to the new file*//     

public class ReadandWriteAByte {
    public void readandWriteBytesToFile(){
        File file = new File("count.char"); //(abcdefghijk)
        File bfile = new File("bytefile.txt");//(New File)
        byte[] b;
        FileInputStream fis = null;              
        FileOutputStream fos = null;          

        try{               
            fis = new FileInputStream (file);           
            fos = new FileOutputStream (bfile);             
            b = new byte [1024];              
            int i;              
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            while ((i = fis.read(b))!=-1){                  
                sb.append(new String(b,5,5));               
                fos.write(b, 2, 5);               
            }               

            System.out.println(sb.toString());               
        }catch (IOException e) {                    
            e.printStackTrace();                
        }finally {               
            try {              
                if(fis != null);           
                    fis.close();    //This helps to close the stream          
            }catch (IOException e){           
                e.printStackTrace();              
            }            
        }               
    }               

    public static void main (String args[]){              
        ReadandWriteAByte rb = new ReadandWriteAByte();              
        rb.readandWriteBytesToFile();              
    }                 
}
```

O/P in console : fghij

O/P in new file :cdefg

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Cactoos](http://www.cactoos.org):

```
new LengthOf(new TeeInput(array, new File("a.txt"))).value();
```

More details: http://www.yegor256.com/2017/06/22/object-oriented-input-output-in-cactoos.html