# Read Bytes from all files in folder

Tags: java

Write program to read bytes from all the files in folder...

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class xmlfile {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File folder = new File ("07072013");
        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

        String filesin;

        BufferedWriter xmlfile = null;
        String outxmlfile = ("07072013\\" + "jayraj" + ".xml");
        int offset = 0;
        int size = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
            if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {

                filesin = listOfFiles[i].getName();

                if (filesin.endsWith("pdf")) {
                    System.out.println(filesin);

                    Path filesin1= Paths.get(filesin);
                    System.out.println(filesin1);

                    xmlfile = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outxmlfile));

                    byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(filesin1);
                    size = bytes.length;

                    xmlfile.append("File = " + filesin1 + ", Offset = " + offset + ", Size = " + size);

                }
            }
        }
         xmlfile.close();
    }
}
```

I am getting error..

```
601688450_eBill_20130708.pdf
601688450_eBill_20130708.pdf
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: 601688450_eBill_20130708.pdf
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileAttributeViews$Basic.readAttributes(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileAttributeViews$Basic.readAttributes(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.readAttributes(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.file.Files.readAttributes(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.file.Files.size(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.file.Files.readAllBytes(Unknown Source)
    at xmlfile.main(xmlfile.java:50)
```

And `System.out.println` only prints one line. If there is 5 files in the folder, it should write 5 lines?

I tried without specifying bytes and size, which gave:

```
File = 601693971_eBill_20130708.pdf, Offset = 0, Size =
```

So why aren't the other files being printed as well?

Comment: [`NoSuchFileException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/NoSuchFileException.html)s are thrown when the target file does not exist. Are you 100% sure that `601688450_eBill_20130708.pdf` exists?

Comment: ya, there is 7 files in folder, and 5 pdf files its include this file as well..I don't what's wrong please help me thanks!!

Comment: can you fix the spacing in your code so that it's easier for us to read please?

Comment: hey, I already remove some spacing so..it's ok?? please let me know!! Thanks!!

Comment: Why not include a `dir`/`ls` listing of the directory in question?

Comment: Maybe, just maybe you need to specify WHERE the files are when you attempt to open them.

Comment: actually, i tried;;  byte[] bytes = filesin.getBytes();
       size = bytes.length; and its worked but it only print one line for 1 file what about other files??    File = 601693971_eBill_20130708.pdf, Offset = 112, Size = 28 what about other files??

Answer (score 0):

You are passing in just the file name to get the Path of the file which Is looking in the wrong directory for the file.

Try this

```
 Path filesin1= Paths.get(filesin.getAbsolutePath());
```

instead of

```
 Path filesin1= Paths.get(filesin);
```

If you want to check add these prints

```
 System.out.println(filesin.getAbsolutePath());
 System.out.println(filesin1.toString());
```

**EDIT** Do these changes an let me know the output

```
public class xmlfile {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File folder = new File ("07072013");
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

    //ADD THIS
    System.out.println("There are " + listOfFiles.length + " files"); 

    String filesin;

    BufferedWriter xmlfile = null;
    // PUT THIS OUTSIDE YOUR LOOP
    xmlfile = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outxmlfile));
    String outxmlfile = ("07072013\\" + "jayraj" + ".xml");
    int offset = 0;
    int size = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
        //ADD THIS
        File f = listOfFiles[i];
        // AND THIS
        System.out.println(i + " " + f.getAbsolutePath());
        if (f.isFile()) {

            filesin = listOfFiles[i].getName();

            if (filesin.endsWith("pdf")) {
                System.out.println(filesin);
                //CHANGE THIS
                Path aPath = Paths.get(f.getAbsolutePath());
                // Change this
                System.out.println(filesin1.toString());

                // CHANGE THIS what you got to work
                byte[] bytes = filesin.getBytes(); // This is actually just getting the bytes of the String probably not what you want
                byte[] actualBytes = Files.readAllBytes(aPath);
                size = actualBytes.length;

                //EDIT THIS (ADD NEWLINE CHAR AT THE END)
                xmlfile.append("File = " + filesin1 + ", Offset = " + offset + ", Size = " + size + "\n");

            }
        }
    }
     xmlfile.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried file.toURI() Getting error rename all file.. can't fix that error.. how to do that?? please help me thanks!!

Comment: actually, i tried;;  byte[] bytes = filesin.getBytes();
       size = bytes.length; and its worked but it only print one line for 1 file what about other files??    File = 601693971_eBill_20130708.pdf, Offset = 112, Size = 28 what about other files??

Comment: Not sure about the error you are getting with the method I posted above. Are all the files in your folder pdf's? and lowercase pdf

Comment: yap.. there is 5 files in folder it should write 5 lines right?? for all 5 files!! I don't know why its not working!! please help me.. Thanks!!

Comment: Look at my edit above, add the changes and let me know the console output

Comment: Hey, I have question.. Its worked!! Thank you soo much!! But Above code i wrote that size it was 28.. and your is 111419 i think yours is correct right?? Thanks once again!!

Comment: Yes thats better. 28 is the length of the String `601693971_eBill_20130708.pdf` meaning it was just the bytes of the String. (1 byte per character)

Comment: ohh ok!!YES thats better?? what that mean?? like yours is correct or mine?? Thank you so much so mine says byte file name right?? your bytes says in file right??

Comment: Yes, Mine is the bytes read from the file, yours was just the bytes of the file name, not what was in the file.

Comment: Hey, Is There any way to write all bytes in text file write 111419 bytes?? Please help me thanks!!

Comment: I suggest you read these [JavaIO tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/). In particular this one about [Reading, writing and creating files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html) or just look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4350084/byte-to-file-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to access `601688450_eBill_20130708.pdf` when you should be trying to access `07072013/601688450_eBill_20130708.pdf`.

Use `Path filesin1 = new File(folder, filesin).toPath()`

Comment: actually, i tried;;  byte[] bytes = filesin.getBytes();
       size = bytes.length; and its worked but it only print one line for 1 file what about other files??    File = 601693971_eBill_20130708.pdf, Offset = 112, Size = 28 what about other files??