# Save itext pdf as blob without physical existence.

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I am using this code to generate PDF using iText. First it creates HTML to PDF after that it converts that PDF in byte array or in BLOB or in byte array. 
I dont want to create any physical stores of pdf on my server. First i want to convert HTML to blob of PDF using itext, And after that i want to store that blob in my DB(Stores in DB i will done).

```
          String userAccessToken=requests.getSession()
                    .getAttribute("access_token").toString();
          Document document = new Document(PageSize.LETTER);
          String name="/pdf/invoice.pdf";
          PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance
               (document, new FileOutputStream(requests.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("")+"/assets"+name));
          document.open();
          document.addAuthor("Real Gagnon");
          document.addCreator("Real's HowTo");
          document.addSubject("Thanks for your support");
          document.addTitle("Please read this ");
          XMLWorkerHelper worker = XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance();

          //data is an html string 
          String str = data;
          worker.parseXHtml(pdfWriter, document, new StringReader(str));
          document.close();
          ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
          PdfWriter.getInstance(document, byteArrayOutputStream);
          byte[] pdfBytes = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();

          link=name;
          System.out.println("Byte array is "+pdfBytes);
```

PROBLEM:- Convert html to pdf BLOB using itext, Without physical existence of PDF.

Comment: What isn't working here?

Comment: No, It's working. But it creates first physical PDF on server, i dont want to create  physical PDF on server (/pdf/invoice.pdf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answer to this question is almost correct, but not quite.

You can use any `OutputStream` when you create a `PdfWriter`. If you want to create a file entirely in memory, you can use a `ByteArrayOutputStream` like this:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
Document document = new Document();
PdfWriter.getInstance(document, baos);
document.open();
// add stuff
document.close();
byte[] pdf = baos.toByteArray();
```

In short: you first create a `ByteArrayOutputStream`, you pass this `OutputStream` to the `PdfWriter` and after the document is closed, you can get the bytes from the `OutputStream`.

(In the other answer, there was no way to retrieve the bytes. Also: it is important that you don't try to retrieve the bytes before the document is closed.)

Comment: How can you get the `document` back from the `byte[]` array?

Comment: Your additional question is unclear. If you want to write the byte array to a file, then you have several options here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4350084/byte-to-file-in-java If you want to further manipulate the PDF, you need to create a `PdfReader` instance. Note that this question is about an old version of iText. In iText 7, the `Document` object is quite different.

Answer (score 0):

Write into a `ByteArrayOutputStream` (instead of a `FileOutputStream`):

```
PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance
           (document, new ByteArrayOutputStream());
```