# How In geb download zip file into the current directory?

Tags: java, grails, groovy, geb

I try to use this function:

```
downloadBytes(exportLink.@href)
```

but I get array of bytes. How can I get zip file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found another solution for saving zip in geb without asking directory.
I configured my GebConfig.groovy :

```
    profile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList",2)
    profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",false)
    profile.setPreference("browser.download.dir", new File("").getAbsolutePath())
    profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","application/zip")
```

Answer (score 1):

A file is nothing but an array of bytes. What do you need to actually do? You can save it somewhere by using a FileOutputStream, for example. 
You can use a ZipInputStream (with a ByteArrayInputStream) to read the entries directly in Java... So, what do you want to actually do?

Comment: I need to save this zip in current directory

Comment: You can write a byte array via the FileOutputStream's write method, which is the most basic way to do it. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4350084/byte-to-file-in-java

Comment: I tried this:
but I can't open zip file

    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filename+".zip");
    fos.write(byteArr);
    fos.close();